# Billing Charges when Querying a DataStudio Report Connected to a View in BiqQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio, cost-management

I have created a report in DataStudio using data pulled from BigQuery and saved as a view. After playing around with the report for a while I have noticed that I have been billed 100+ times for the query (all the exact same size of data), but I only ran it once to build the view. Am I getting charged every time I interact with the report e.g. apply a filter? If not, what is causing these costs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your report will run a query against the view for each element on the page so 4 graphs = 4 queries.

If you then change a filter for example, that will run a further 4 queries (assuming the filter affects them all).